# Postgis, convert point to line

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis

well,

I have points or coordinates from latitude and longitude. I wanted to combine two points to create lines using something like this:

select gid,st_makeline (geom) from(select gig,long,lat,geom from capa0 order by gid) t1group by gid

But I don't know if I'm okay.

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`st_makeline`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_MakeLine.html) function and a window function, something like:

```
SELECT st_makeline(startpoint, endpoint)
FROM (SELECT st_makepoint(lag(long) OVER w, lag(lat) OVER w) AS startpoint,
             st_makepoint(long, lat) AS endpoint
      FROM capa0
      WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY gid)
     ) AS subq
WHERE startpoint IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: it only returns 1 value, i want to join two points to make a line, i have thousands of points

Comment: I see. I have changed the answer.